# Wordpress missing blog permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I set up my Wordpress website, imported all blog post and submitted my sitemap to Google last month.

I realized that my blog posts appear like: www.domain.com/blog-post-name <- without the /blog/ directory. I can add the blog directory by changing the Wordpress permalinks, but then when someone goes to the old blog URL, they get a 404 error.

Is it possible to direct users who go to www.domain.com/blog-post-name to www.domain.com/blog/blog-post-name

Thanks

Comment: So all links should now be www.domain.com/blog/whatever?

Comment: @Howlin Yes, but I don't want any broken links either: so when a user goes to www.domain.com/blog-post-name, they will be directed to www.domain.com/blog/blog-post-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you (changing the `www.domain.com` to your domain) :

```
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all those to insert /blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:
This will rewrite specific urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog-post1$ http://www.example.com/blog/blog-post1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog-post2$ http://www.example.com/blog/blog-post2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This code works, but it's also rewriting my index.php page to www.domain.com/blog/index.php <- I would like it to only rewrite blog posts that are currently in the /blog/ directory.

Comment: How many blog posts are pointing to the wrong link? (http://example.com/blog-post instead of http://example.com/blog/blog-post)

Comment: I have edited my post. If there aren't too many blog posts then you could use the example I have added.

Comment: I have around 40 blog posts... do I need to add that htaccess line for each post?

Comment: Yes for those you would add 40 lines of `RewriteRule ^blog-post1$ http://www.example.com/blog/blog-post1 [R=301,L]` and changing blog-post1 to the blog name.